# Map from one interface to another

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, backend

I'm coming from Java and I usually use DTO to map to Entity and vice-versa. But I'm having a hard time to do this in Typescript + Nodejs. What I have are two interfaces:

```
export interface IOne {
    clientId: number;
    clientName: string;
    ...
}

export interface ITwo {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
    ...
}
```

A GET call is received on Interface One format and Interface Two is responsible to grab this response and make a POST request after.

The bellow implementation gets `undefined`:

```
let userTwo: ITwo;

userTwo.map(data => {
    return <ITwo> {
        userId: data.clientId,
        userName: data.clientName,
        ...
    };
});
```

What is the right way in Typescript/Nodejs to Map the returned response in one interface format then convert to another Interface format in DTO to Domain Object pattern?

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Hi @MajedBadawi I've edited, basically gets undefined and I'm not sure if this is the best practice for what is intended.

Comment: ``Array#map`` returns an array, so you need to assign it to a variable

Comment: What do you mean by "gets undefined"? Where is `map` coming from? Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (see link)](//tsplay.dev/WkjZDm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (with no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
export interface IOne {
    clientId: number;
    clientName: string;
    ...
}

export interface ITwo {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
    ...
}

const toDTO = (input: IOne): ITwo => {
  return {
    userId: input.clientId,
    userName: input.clientName
  }
}

const handleReq = (req) => {
  // we assume you have to tell Typescript what userOne is
  const userOne = req.userOne as IOne[]
  // userTwo will be typed as ITwo[] or Array<ITwo> through inference
  const userTwo = userOne.map(u => toDTO(u))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A comprehensive guide to how to implement DTOs in TypeScript can be found in the following article:

https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/typescript-domain-driven-design/repository-dto-mapper/

It contains more details, but it also shows the good practices of implementing what you asked.